# Coral Edge TPU USB Accelerator driver fails to install

Tags: windows-10, google-coral

I'm trying to install and test my Coral Edge TPU. I'm following the instructions here: https://coral.ai/docs/accelerator/get-started/

The first step is to install drivers from the coral website, but I'm getting the following errors. I've tried running with and without admin, and uninstalling and installing again, but I get the same errors.

Has anyone else run into this issue? I'm on Windows 10.

```
Installing UsbDk                                                                                                       
Installing Windows drivers                                                                                             
Microsoft PnP Utility                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
Adding driver package:  coral.inf                                                                                      
Driver package added successfully.                                                    
Published Name:         oem69.inf                                                                                                                                                                                                              
Adding driver package:  Coral_USB_Accelerator.inf                                                                      
Failed to add driver package: The hash for the file is not present in the specified catalog file. The file is likely corrupt or the victim of tampering.                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Adding driver package:  Coral_USB_Accelerator_(DFU).inf                                                                
Failed to add driver package: The hash for the file is not present in the specified catalog file. The file is likely corrupt or the victim of tampering.                                                                                                                                                                                                               
Total driver packages:  3                                                                                              
Added driver packages:  1                                                                                              
Installing performance counters                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Info: Provider {aaa5bf9e-c44b-4177-af65-d3a06ba45fe7} defined in
C:\Users\User\Downloads\edgetpu_runtime_20201204\edgetpu_runtime\third_party\coral_accelerator_windows\coral.man is already installed in system repository.                   Info: Successfully installed performance counters in
C:\Users\User\Downloads\edgetpu_runtime_20201204\edgetpu_runtime\third_party\coral_accelerator_windows\coral.manCopying edgetpu and libusb to System32                                            1 file(s) copied.                                                                                                      
1 file(s) copied.                                                                                              
Install complete                                                                                                       
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in the coral software. According to this thread https://github.com/google-coral/edgetpu/issues/260 they messed up a few things in the newest version (at the time 2.5.0). Starting with a fresh virtual environment and using the release 2.1.0 and corresponding driver for Python 3.7 (3.8, 3.9 not supported as of 2.1.0) fixed the issue.

From that thread:

> For now, I suggest rolling back to the older driver:
> https://dl.google.com/coral/edgetpu_api/edgetpu_runtime_20200728.zip
>
> And you also need to remove your current tflite_runtime and downgrade
> it to an older version (make sure to change to the right python
> version):
>
> pip3 install
> https://dl.google.com/coral/python/tflite_runtime-2.1.0.post1-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl
> pip3 install
> https://dl.google.com/coral/python/tflite_runtime-2.1.0.post1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
> Apologies, we are working to get this fixed ASAP

Answer (score 1):

we recently uploaded a new package this should fix this:
https://dl.google.com/coral/edgetpu_api/edgetpu_runtime_20210119.zip

source: coral.ai/software

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable driver signature enforcement using the advanced boot menu. After that you can install it. You can do that by going to going to the Settings app >> go to the “Update and Security -> Recovery” page. Click on the “Restart now” button under the “Advanced Startup” section.